# Show attribute data anywhere on the website using product ID

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-attribute

What I want to do is show the price of a particular configurable product using its ID anywhere on the website?

I'm learning as I go.

Answer (score 1):

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->load($productId);

$price = $product->getFinalPrice();
$formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($price->getFinalPrice(), true, false);
```

now you can do what ever you need with `$price` or `$formattedPrice`.
`$price` will be something like `19.9900` and `$formattedPrice` will be `€ 19.99`

Comment: And how would I display the price?

Comment: Just echo it...

Comment: outside of the product page? where do I enter the product ID?

Comment: `$productId` might be the $productId. Just a guess.